# Comparators (greater than or less than symbols) not showing up when used with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to use comparators along with siunitx to express some values. In page 20 of the siunitx manual, the last line says:

```
In addition to signs, siunitx can recognise comparators, such as <. The packageinput-comparators
will automatically carry out conversions for «, », <= and >= to \ll, \gg, \le and \ge,
respectively.
```

Thus, in my test code below, I have written:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}

\begin{document}
Temperature levels were higher than threshold (\qty{>40}{\celsius}).
\end{document}
```

And get the corresponding output:

[image: Output]

I understand that I can simply use `\textgreater` before the `\qty{}{}` macro and call it a day, but I am curious as to why I am receiving such an output despite the manual providing the examples. Have I missed something in the preamble?. This output persists even when comment out the `\sisetup{mode=text}` option.

Comment: In your example, the `>` is not part of the `siunitx` input. Put them inside: `\qty[>40}{\celsius}`. The next page in the manual shows examples on how to use them.

Comment: I am so sorry, I manually typed the code in instead of copy paste. I have made the correct. the error persists. Is there a way to use comparators in the text mode as well?

Comment: You need to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `atkinson`, [I guess](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/atkinsonhyperlegible/).

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. But I cannot seem to have the option to mark your comment as the answer.